# Can I send requests to the server from HTML rendered in email?

Tags: django, email, html-email, email-client, django-email

I am trying to implement the following functionality.

The server sends an email to a user who doesn't necessarily have an account in the server.
In the email, the user is asked to rate a certain model (send a request to the server).

Can I make it in such a way that the user can click the button and doesn't get redirected to some other page, but sends the request directly to the server.

```
<div>
    <p> Hi {{ user }},  </p> 
    This e mail is to kindly ask you to rate {{ job_seeker }}, who previously
     worked with you.
     
 
    Please rate him from 1 to 3 below.
    
    <button onclick="some function that wont work in email">1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>

 </div>
```

I am using django.

Comment: Can share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Sumithran I tried to include some JavaScript to send the request, but when I click on the button from email, the browser just ignores the script part.

Comment: please share the code..

Comment: @Sumithran I edited the question for you to see the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, you cant execute JavaScript in email templates.

Due to serious security issues, most of the email clients block JavaScript from executing. that's why your *redirection* script doesn't work.

the solution is to use an `<a>` tag with a URL that specifies the page link instead of `<button>`.

Comment: So the most I can do is to include a link right? Basically I can send only GET requests to the server via <a> tags